# global variable not defined in django

Tags: python, django, global-variables, sms, verify

I have a problem with this code in django
I have defined two global variables

But Django does not identify them

my view:

```
global phone,rand_num
def phone_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhoneLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            phone = f"0{form.cleaned_data['phone']}"
            rand_num = randint(1000, 9999)
            api = KavenegarAPI('mytoken!')
            params = { 'sender' : '', 'receptor': phone , 'message' : rand_num }
            api.sms_send(params)
            return redirect('account:verify')

    else :
        form = PhoneLoginForm()
    return render(request,'account/phone_login.html',{'form':form})


def verify(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VerifyCodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if rand_num == form.cleaned_data['code']:
                profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, phone = phone)
                user = get_object_or_404(User,profile__id = profile.id)
                login(request,user)
                messages.success(request,'logged in successfully' , 'success')
                return redirect('popasssts:all_posts')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'your code is wrong','warning')
                
    else:
        form = VerifyCodeForm()
    return render(request,'account/verify.html',{'form' : form})
```

my urls :

```
path('verify/',views.verify,name='verify'),
```

i have this error :

```
NameError at /account/verify/

name 'rand_num' is not defined

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/verify/
Django Version:     3.0.7
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

name 'rand_num' is not defined
```

---

I want the user to enter the site after entering the SMS code.

Comment: Your code is not thread-safe. Imagine it would work, then every new user resets the code for every verification still in progress. Don't use global variables in web applications, use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caution:** Global variables violates maybe the most important principle of the programming, the encapsulation. Using them, will turn your code to a spaghetti. Don't use them. (Unless there is another way)

Here is what encapsulation means:

> ...Encapsulation refers to the bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data, or the restricting of direct access to some of an object's components.

*Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))*

If you really want to use it, here is your problem: `global` keyword should be used in functions.

Let's try that way:

```py
phone = ""
rand_num = 0

def phone_login(request):
    global phone, rand_num
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...

def verify(request):
    global phone, rand_num
    if request.method == "POST":
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the global variables, you need to put the `global` keyword inside the functions and assign initial values to the variables outside:

```py
phone = ""
rand_num = -1

def phone_login(request):
    global phone, rand_num
    # ...

def verify(request):
    global phone, rand_num
    # ...
```

With this approach, the values of `phone` and `rand_num` are shared among all users of the application. If your application have multiple users, a better approach would be to store the values in the current user's session:

```py
def phone_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...

        if form.is_valid():
            # ...

            # Save the values in the session
            request.session["phone"] = phone
            request.session["rand_num"] = rand_num

            # ...


def verify(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # ...

        if form.is_valid():
            # Get the values from the session, setting
            # default values in case they don't exist.
            phone = request.session.get("phone", "")
            rand_num = request.session.get("rand_num", -1)

            # ...
```

For using sessions, the `django.contrib.sessions` application must be enabled in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list of the **settings.py** file of the Django project. Also, this application must be migrated to the project's database with the command `python manage.py migrate`.

In the official [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) you have more information about sessions.